# JUnit :java.lang.IllegalStateException while executin event.queue() where event is ValueChangeEvent instance

Tags: java, documentum

While creating Junit of a method which takes `valueChangeEvent` object as input, it is throwing an `IllegalStateException` while calling the queue method.

I have searched a few things which leads me to the conclusion that this is occurring because of 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException` - if the source component for this event is not a descendant of a `UIViewRoot`.

How can I make `valueChangeEvent` component  a  descendant of a `UIViewRoot`?

Comment: can you add your code?